# Deciphering the magic(5) man page

Tags: file, format

I have been poring over the "magic(5)" man page (the most recent one from the main site).

I would like to better understand the actual semantics of indirect addressing, also considering the fact that the man page does not really provide a grammar for said addresses.

First of all the "grammar" for indirect addresses seems to be

```
(( x [.[bislBISL]][+-][ y ])
```

Alas, the double parentheses at the beginning don't seem right.

Next, the examples "extend" this definition by showing examples and commenting on them.  One thing one immediately gets is that the `[+-]` should probably be `[-+*/^|&%]` (in proper regexp form).

Finally there is the issue about the `y` in the definition.  It turns out that this can be either a regular "number" (how long? unsigned? signed?) **or** another *offset* as in the example below, with more parentheses (cfr., the `(-4)`).

```
0                 string       MZ
>0x18             leshort      >0x3f
>>(0x3c.l)        string       PE\0\0 PE executable (MS-Windows)
# search for the PE section called ".idata"...
>>>&0xf4          search/0x140 .idata
# ...and go to the end of it, calculated from start+length;
# these are located 14 and 10 bytes after the section name
>>>>(&0xe.l+(-4)) string       PK\3\4 \b, ZIP self-extracting archive
```

Now.  Apart from the grammar issues, can anybody please tell me exactly how you get the address to read from in the last example?

Assuming you have a `pos` position coming from the `search` test for `.idata` (which it appears to be this `start + length`), and reformulating the indirect address with the following "variables" (`<relative tag>`, `<offset1>`, `<op>`, and `<offset2>`), how do you get the final offset?

```
(<relative tag><offset1>[.,]<op>(<offset2>))
```

... and how do you compute it in this case? (Where `<y>` is a number?)

```
(<relative tag><offset1>[.,]<op><y>)
```

Apologies for being obtuse.  I just want reassurances.

Thank you

MA

Comment: I found out that the git repository has a BNF description on the magic format (a mirror is here: https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/src/BNF).